# Swift 2 Search Bar with Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, swift, swift2

I'm sending to PHP using `$_POST['find']`  inside `PHP` I generate `echo json_encode($records);` table

My question is how I can show the result : "records" in my tableview cells

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to parse the JSON response and store it in an array.

For example, using [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), you can parse the response with [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). Create an array of your records, and use that when getting data for a tableview cell.